# C++ Eclipse: Debugging with optirun/primusrun on Linux

Tags: eclipse, gdb, eclipse-cdt

How can I debug my Program with optirun or primusrun? When simply running it, I can use the workaround of running primusrun with my program as parameter, but this does not work for debugging. I tried replacing "gdb" with "primusrun gdb" and starting eclipse with primusrun but it does not do anything.

Answer (score 3):

You can start Eclipse under `primusrun`. `gdb` and the debbugged process will "inherit" this, thus running themselves on the discrete card.

Unfortunately, this means that Eclipse itself is also holding the card active, thereby increasing the power consumption.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having to start Eclipse using `optirun`, you can change the command used to launch GDB as follows:

1. Click on "Debug configurations..." on the Run menu.
2. Click on the launch configuration for your application.
3. Go to the Debugger tab.
4. Change the "GDB debugger" field to `optirun gdb`.

Answer (score 0):

On my system (eclipse neon, Debian stretch), you have to put a absolute path to make this working (/usr/bin/optirun gdb).

For Run Configurations another solution is to set optirun (absolute path) as "C/C++ Application" and the name of your Application (e.g. "Debug/appName") as an Argument ("Arguments" Tab, "Program arguments").